# Copy tuple with modification

Tags: julia

I have a tuple:

```
my_tup=(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8,i=9)
```

I would like to modify a value in this tuple. Because tuples are immutable, the obvious route doesn't work:

```
my_tup[:a]=50 #Raises an error, as expected
```

So to perform the modification, I'd like to copy the tuple and its elements while changing the target element.

My current solution is as follows:

```
my_tup=(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8,i=9)
args = keys(my_tup)
NamedTuple{args}(i!=:a ? getfield(my_tup, i) : 50 for i in args)
```

But this seems verbose or as though there should already be a function for it in the standard library.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

You can [`merge`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.merge) two named tuples:

```
julia> xs = (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

julia> ys = merge(xs, (; a = 50))
(a = 50, b = 2, c = 3)
```

Comment: Note that with `merge` you can also perform "dynamic" merges: `merge(xs, [:c => 4])`, which is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 2):

David Varela has the correct answer, "use `merge`".  It is an important technique.

- *To make this solution more easily available to others, here are some examples.*

**on creating plain Tuples (unnamed Tuples) and NamedTuples**

Both Tuples and NamedTuples are constructed using parentheses:

```
julia> a_tuple = (1, 2)
(1, 2)

julia> a_namedtuple = (a = 1, b = 2)
(a = 1, b = 2)
```

If we try construct a Tuple or a NamedTuple with exactly one entry that same way, it does not work; instead the values are assigned named variables directly.

```
julia> not_a_tuple = ("xyz");
julia> not_a_tuple, typeof(not_a_tuple)
("xyz", String)

julia> not_a_namedtuple = (abc = "xyz");
julia> not_a_namedtuple, typeof(not_a_namedtuple)
("xyz", String)
```

To construct Tuples and NamedTuples that have a single value, we let Julia know that we are working with [Named]Tuples.  An easy way to do this, and one that works for both kinds of Tuples, is to add a comma ',' before the closing parenthesis. For visual emphasis, I separate the commas from the values; it is not necessary to do that in your source code.

```
julia> a_tuple = (0.5 ,)
(0.5,)

julia> a_namedtuple = (onehalf = 0.5 ,)
(onehalf = 0.5,)
```

**on substituting values in NamedTuples**

```
julia> namedtuple = (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3);  # the initial NamedTuple
julia> changes_to_make = (b = 0 ,);         # the modifications intended

julia> changed_namedtuple = merge(namedtuple, changes_to_make)
(a = 1, b = 0, c = 3)
```

```
julia> namedtuple = (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3);  # the initial NamedTuple
julia> changes_to_make = (b = 0, c = 7);    # the modifications intended

julia> changed_namedtuple = merge(namedtuple, changes_to_make)
(a = 1, b = 0, c = 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
julia> my_tup=(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8,i=9)
(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3,d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, g = 7, h = 8, i = 9)

julia> new_one = (my_tup..., a=50)
(a = 50, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, g = 7, h = 8, i = 9)
```

Comment: Why is it that when I do `(my_tup..., )`, the names are dropped, but with `(my_tup..., a=50)` they are retained?

Comment: Hi, that's how `iter` for NamedTuples are defined. `(my_tup...,)` matches the behaviour of `for xxx in my_tup`. To copy without modifiacation, use `(;my_tup...)`